# what is the method for sending SMS in android?

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to send a text message and my code ain't working. Can anyone help me out with that?
I tried using code given in tutorials point but its not working.

```
protected void sendSMSMessage() { 
    Log.i("Send SMS", ""); 
    String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString(); 
    String message = txtMessage.getText().toString(); 
    try { 
       SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo,null,message,null,null); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); e.printStackTrace(); } 
    }
```

Comment: Do you have sufficient balance? Have you given the proper permissions? Post the code that you are using.

Comment: protected void sendSMSMessage() {
Log.i("Send SMS", "");
String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
try {
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo,null,message,null,null);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
e.printStackTrace();
}
   }

Comment: I have edited your question, and move the code in your question for better reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Also check this [Sending a SMS Message from an Android Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463338/Sending-a-SMS-Message-from-an-Android-Application)

Comment: @user3608017:- Check out the link which I have added in my answer. That will help you!

Answer (score 0):

It's SMSManager.sendTextMessage.  Remember to request permission in your manifest.

Comment: No, it's trivial.  Google it and you'll find hundreds of examples.